# Assign names to multiple data frames from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, global-variables

I've converted a list of csv files into a separate data frames, each with unique name generated from a string, i.e. in pseudo code: df1 = data frame from csv1, df2 = data frame from csv2. It works fine. However, I suspect my method for naming the data frames is not the correct use of globals(). Is there a better way to assign a string to a data frame variable?

```
def csv_to_df(csv_list):
'''Takes a list of input csv files as strings. Converts the file names to pandas dataframes.
The data frames are assigned names df1, df2, df3...dfn'''
# make a list of dataframes
df_list = ['df' + str(item) for item in range(1, len(csv_list) + 1)]
for x, y in zip(df_list, csv_list):
    globals()[x] = pd.read_csv(y, header=None,names=['Time', 'Temp'],  delimiter='\t')

files = ['../data/something', '../data/something else',
     '../data/something else here', '../data/something for sure',
     '../data/something sometimes']

csv_to_df(files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to save them all as global variables?  That seems like it would be a real pain to recover them again.

I'd change df_list to instead hold the data frames

```
def csv_to_df(csv_list):
'''Takes a list of input csv files as strings. Converts the file names to pandas dataframes.
The data frames are assigned names df1, df2, df3...dfn'''
# make a dictionary of dataframes
df_dict = {}
for i, df in enumerate(csv_list):
    df_dict['df' + str(i+1)] = pd.read_csv(y, header=None,names=['Time', 'Temp'],  delimiter='\t')

files = ['../data/something', '../data/something else',
     '../data/something else here', '../data/something for sure',
     '../data/something sometimes']

csv_to_df(files)
```

Then instead of getting df1, you'd get df_dict['df1'].  You could even just put them straight in a list and get them by index.

```
def csv_to_df(csv_list):
'''Takes a list of input csv files as strings. Converts the file names to pandas dataframes.
The data frames are assigned names df1, df2, df3...dfn'''
# make a list of dataframes
df_list = []
for df in csv_list:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(y, header=None,names=['Time', 'Temp'],  delimiter='\t'))

files = ['../data/something', '../data/something else',
     '../data/something else here', '../data/something for sure',
     '../data/something sometimes']

csv_to_df(files)
```

Then instead of df1, you'd get df_list[0].

Comment: Thanks. Your solution makes sense. I'm still curious as to how to properly auto assign the data frames to variables within a function.

Comment: There isn't really a proper way to do that, since you shouldn't really be programatically creating variables inside a module.  The way you did it probably is the best way if you insist on doing that, but if you have a collection of objects you should keep them inside a collection.